# GAE Datastore CRON loop within a CRON

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-datastore

My cron requirement is as below:

The cron works for every first 40 minutes of the hour and rest for 20 minutes.

Can I make that in a single cron entry?

```
every 10 minutes from 00:00 to 00:40
every 10 minutes from 01:00 to 01:40
every 10 minutes from 02:00 to 02:40
every 10 minutes from 03:00 to 03:40
every 10 minutes from 04:00 to 04:40
.
.
every 10 minutes from 23:00 to 23:40
```

Comment: Could you provide your YAML file for this job? Also the code that gets run, and if you see any error in the logs.

Comment: I fixed the issue with the below design.

Cron 1: every 60 minutes from 00:00 to 23:00 //enables a service

Cron 2: every 60 minutes from 00:40 to 23:40 //stops the service

Cron 3: every 10 minutes from 00:00 to 23:40 //Does the work if the service is on.


Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create either multiple crons, or multiple entries for your cron (not entirely sure it can be done, but I think you can just create one entry for 10:00-10:40, one for 11:00-11:40, etc... all targeting the same cron job), the only way I can think about doing that is to have a check at the beginning of your cron... something like (pseudo code, since I don't know if you do Java, Python, PhP, or Go):

time = getTime()

if(!(time == xx:40 OR time == xx:50))
{
//cron job's code
}

Not elegant, but will do what you want.  In a single cron entry, you can't, according to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Java_appengine_web_xml_The_schedule_format)(Java) or [this one](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_The_schedule_format) (Python).

Having looked at [Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2237) I actually found that this is the solution they suggest as well (for now)